# Connecting a form with console

Tags: c#

I'm creating a project in visual studio 2017 and I need to fill a check box on a form that I created with the name of the text file that I previously create and send them into an FTP server.
Is that possible?
Here's some of my code, feel free to ask about more code:

Creates the file and saves it:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\Faturas Teste\\Fatura " + _transaction.TransDocNumber + ".txt"))
{
    string numcont = _transaction.PartyFederalTaxID;
    double numenc = _transaction.BillToPartyID;
    double numfatura = _transaction.TransDocNumber;
    DateTime data = _transaction.CreateDate;
    double valor = _transaction.TotalAmount;
    int zona = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressID;
    string zona2 = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressLine2;
    double precoantesdisc = bsoItemTrans.BSOItemTransactionDetail.TransactionDetail.PackUnitPrice;
    double preconet = transaction.TotalTransactionAmount;
    double quantidade = transaction.Details.Count;
    string bonus = "0";
    string valorStr = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string preconetStr = preconet.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string precoantesdiscStr = precoantesdisc.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data:dd/MM/yyyy};{valorStr};{zona};");
    foreach (ItemTransactionDetail detail in transaction.Details)
    {
        var item = MyApp.DSOCache.ItemProvider.GetItem(detail.ItemID, MyApp.SystemSettings.BaseCurrency);
        double taxRate = MyApp.DSOCache.TaxesProvider.GetTaxRateFromTaxableGroupID(detail.TaxableGroupID, "PRT", "CON");
        string barcode = item.BarCode;
        writer.WriteLine($"{barcode};{taxRate};{precoantesdiscStr};{preconetStr};{quantidade};{bonus}");
    }

}

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data source = 2c4138928627\Sage ; Database=ARMINDOData ; User Id=sa ; Password=sage2008+");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXZona', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXZona(IDZona int,Morada char(50));", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UXZona(FirstColumn, SecondColumn) VALUES (@0, @1)", conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXZona', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXZona(IDZona int,Morada char(50));", conn);

MessageBox.Show("gravou");
```

Form code:

On the form I just have an empty Checklist and a submit button.

UPDATE

Added 2 screenshots to be more specific

Here I've the textfile I've created with the code above

[image]

And I need to put the name of that file inside this checklist and then when I press the submit button it sends the textfile to an FTP server that I have.

[image]

UPDATE 2:
Added some code that M Idrees gave me.

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        void LoadFileNames()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\Faturas Teste";
            string fileNameOnly = "";
            foreach (var item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")) // here you can change file extension according to your needs.
            {
                fileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(fileNameOnly); // actually adding files names to checkbox listing
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151621/discussion-on-question-by-joao-costa-connecting-a-form-with-console).

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you have `CheckedListBox` control (name `checkedListBox1`) added on your form. And need to add items to this by getting files from some directory. If this is OK. You can use this code:

```
private void LoadFileNames()
{
    string path = @"C:\Path\To\Directory";
    string fileNameOnly = "";
    foreach (var item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt")) // here you can change file extension according to your needs.
    {
         fileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
         checkedListBox1.Items.Add(fileNameOnly); // actually adding files names to checkbox listing
    }
}
```

You can call this function from `Form_Load` event, or some other event where you need.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoadFileNames();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added some screenshots if It helps in someway.

Comment: I've tested and the checklist was empty

Comment: What path you have set, and are there any ".txt" files exists in that directory. Have you called this function from Form_Load event ?

Comment: The path I used is the same where I save those text file. In this case is this `C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\Faturas Teste`. Yes I did.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: I dont need that `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoadFileNames();
}  `
because I load the form from another source